# WebAssembly.instantiate is slower in Node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, webassembly, netlify-function

I am working on using WebAssembly in Node.js (Netlify Functions, which internally uses AWS Lambda).

The problem is that it takes as long as 24s for `WebAssembly.instantiate` to finish.
The size of the `.wasm` file is about 9MB. It is a sheet music library called webmscore (https://github.com/LibreScore/webmscore).

I also tried separating `WebAssembly.instantiate` into two steps: `WebAssembly.compile` to compile module and `WebAssembly.instantiate` to instantiate the module. In this case, `compile` takes 24s, while `instantiate` finishes very quickly.

In the local environment (Node in Windows 10), `WebAssembly.instantiate` takes about 5s. In the client side (Chrome browser), it takes less than 1s. So, I expected it to finish soon in the deployed Node.js environment as well, but it doesn't. Is it normal for the instantiation to take a longer time in deployed Node.js than in other environments? Is there any way to make it faster?